# Definition of a Module.

Tags: python

This may be a silly question to ask. I know that by definition it means "each of a set of standardized parts or independent units that can be used to construct a more complex structure, such as an item of furniture or a building", but if you put it in python's context, is a module equivalent to a python .py file?

Comment: Maybe you should read this [Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

The official definition of a Python module can be found on Python's Glossary page under ["module"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module):

> An object that serves as an organizational unit of Python code. Modules have a namespace containing arbitrary Python objects. Modules
> are loaded into Python by the process of [importing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-importing).

Similarly, a package is officially defined under ["package"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package):

> A Python module which can contain submodules or recursively, subpackages. Technically, a package is a Python module with an
> `__path__` attribute.
>
> See also [regular package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-regular-package) and [namespace package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-namespace-package).

That said, many Python programmers use the term "module" to simply mean a `.py` file.  Most of the time, going into great detail like this just gets in the way of progress.  So, I'd say its fine to generally associate the term with source files.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking yes a module is a python file or a class. But. It depends on your design and file structure. I will present you with some scenaria.

You have a mod.py file with 10 classes. You can import them like this

```
import mod.Class1 as class1
import mod.Class2 as class2
so on..
```

However the traditional way we think of a module can be seen in python under this schema where functionality is bundled.

```
packagename
   __init__.py
   smt.py
   smtelse.py
   packageFunctionalityWrapper.py
```

and then you can import in various ways.

```
from packagename.packageFunctionalityWrapper import aClass
#or whatever way you did this
```

**In summary:** What we call module (in design) is a sub-component that "bundles" functionality. What python calls a module is something entirely else, but can conform to this definition. It is up to your hand and design to decide how you will call and make modules.